# "at" or "on" before "10.10.2019, 16:30" (JavasScript `toLocaleString` output)

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence

Let's consider a time format: "10.10.2019, 16:30". I'd like to use it in a sentence. By example, what would be a correct sentence:

- "It started at 10.10.2019, 16:30.",
- "It started on 10.10.2019, 16:30.",

or maybe neither of them?
For me it seem to depend on what the grammar rule is: in this kind of formats (with one or many commas), should the focus be put on the first information presented (date in this case and so "on" shall be used), the last one (time in this example and "at" shall be used then), it depends on the writers intention and context and what is the most important information for him or her or there is no rule about it?

From what I've already found it seems the best option would be: "It started on 10.10.2019 at 16:30", but as it's a generated output of some (`toLocaleString`) JavaScript function, I'd rather keep this format.

I believe I could also use "Start time: 10.10.2019, 16:30.", but I'm more into not using ":".

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Are you sending this information locally or to another part of the world? If the latter, you need to consider that date and time formats vary. What means one thing to you might mean something different in another location.

Comment: *It started **on** 10.10.2019 **at** 16:30* - OR *It started **at** 16:30 **on** 10.10.2019*. It's always ***on*** dates, ***at*** times in English.

Comment: As KT wrote, date formats can be ambiguous, such as 1.2.2019. JavaScript (and other computer languages) generate the text, but there is no reason why you can't rearrange it to be unambiguous, with the month as text: for example 1 Feb 2019. I would use the first three letters, as is traditional, and not a nonsensical system as invented by the national rail company in UK.

Comment: @WeatherVane the non-standard abbreviations are supposed to be easier to distinguish/harder to alter from one month to another https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/APTIS_ticket_features

Comment: @KillingTime, I think You're right, thank You. In this case the exact format depends on the users browser or system language I believe. It could be treated as an information send locally if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I updated the description, I hope it's now no, or at least less, 'opinion-based'.

Answer (score 1):

In English "on" is generally used for a day

> It started on Tuesday
>
> It started on the 23rd of January

whereas "at" is used for times:

> It started at 4:30pm
>
> It started at midday on Tuesday

Since you are talking about a time, **"at" would be the right choice**.

The format you are choosing is not a natural one in English, but since you seem to be dedicated to keeping it, treat it as just an arbitrary specifier of a time, not grammatically different from "4:30pm on Tuesday"

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Considering that this format is not natural in English, is using "Start time: 10.10.2019, 16:30." a better option in Your opinion?

Comment: It depends if you want what you write to sound like natural English, or like computer-speak.

Comment: I think I would rather have it more like natural English, but I would not like to make a mistake. Thank You.